# Getting probability for an NER entity in spacy v3

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I want to get the probabilities for a spacy NER prediction. I have seen this post [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/881) which shows how to do it and gives the code below.

```
beam_width = 16
beam_density = 0.0001 
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

with nlp.disable_pipes('ner'):
    docs = list(nlp.pipe(texts))
beams = nlp.entity.beam_parse(docs, beam_width=beam_width, beam_density=beam_density)

for doc, beam in zip(docs, beams):
    entity_scores = defaultdict(float)
    for score, ents in nlp.entity.moves.get_beam_parses(beam):
        for start, end, label in ents:
            entity_scores[(start, end, label)] += score
```

However, this code is for spacy v2 and it doesn't work with spacy v3. Specifically I get the error that *'English' object has no attribute 'entity'*. This is because *nlp* doesn't have an *entity* attribute.

Any help on how to do this in spacy v3 using the above code or otherwise?

Comment: In v3 you should use spancat instead, which provides probabilities.

Comment: I don't think this can be used with the out of the box models though. doesn't it require me to train my own model?

Comment: That's correct, you would need to train your own model.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for spacy v3 where entity is replaced by nlp.get_pipe("ner")

```
import spacy
# Number of alternate analyses to consider. More is slower, and not necessarily better -- you need to experiment on your problem.
from collections import defaultdict
beam_width = 18
# This clips solutions at each step. We multiply the score of the top-ranked action by this value, and use the result as a threshold. This prevents the parser from exploring options that look very unlikely, saving a bit of efficiency. Accuracy may also improve, because we've trained on greedy objective.
beam_density = 0.0001
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
text = ["Paris is wonderful"]
docs = list(nlp.pipe(text))
beams = nlp.get_pipe("ner").beam_parse(docs, beam_width=beam_width, 
beam_density=beam_density)

for doc, beam in zip(docs, beams):
    entity_scores = defaultdict(float)
    for score, ents in nlp.get_pipe("ner").moves.get_beam_parses(beam):
        for start, end, label in ents:
            token_ent = doc[start:end]
            entity_scores[(token_ent,start, end, label)] += score
print(entity_scores)
```

However, the probability of some entity is then simply the sum of the scores of the parses containing it, normalized by the total score assigned to all parses in the beam. So it is not the marginal probability of an entity belonging to a class over other classes.